# Get searchstring and the first date that was found above the searchstring

Tags: regex, powershell

```
$PartialResult = Foreach ($String in $MyStrings)
{Select-String -Path 'C:\MyWebsite.html' -list "(.*?)$String(.*?)|'\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d'" -Context 2,1}
```

shows me my searchstring and a date, two lines above.
This works fine!

But sometimes the date is 3, or maybe seven, or  more lines above.
How can I get my searchstring and the first date that was found above the searchstring?

Comment: can you please post some example dates, 3 digits? format such as dd.MM.yyyy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but I think this should work:

```
$PartialResult = Foreach ($String in $MyStrings)
{
  $regex = '(?ms)(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d).+?({0})' -f [regex]::Escape($String)
  if ( (Get-Content 'C:\MyWebsite.html' -Raw) -match $regex )
    { $Matches[1,2] }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work. This regex find the first date of the first string of $mystrings (Also the right searchstring). But then it take the same, first date for all other strings in $mystrings that was found. Example of html page: 07.08.15, UselessString, OneofMYstring1, UselessString, 09.08.15, UselessString, OneofMYstring2. Result with your regex: 07.08.15, OneofMYstring1, 07.08.15, OneofMYstring2. But i need 07.08.15, OneofMYstring1, 09.08.15, OneofMYstring2